# How to analyze/translate "exit status"

Tags: visual-studio, exit-code

I'm analyzing the reason of my VS crash.

I see the exit status is `-532462766`. Based on my research, most of exit code is like `0xE0434352`. What's their difference? Hexadecimal or decimal? 
How can I convert `-532462766` to the format of `0xE0434352`?

Answer (score 0):

> What's their difference? Hexadecimal or decimal?

Yes.  The first `-53462766` is an integer representation of the error `0xE0434352`.

> How can I convert `-532462766` to the format of `0xE0434352`?

Easiest:

Use the windows calculator. Set it to programmer mode (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>), select `DWORD` and `Dec` from the options on the left. Enter the error code. Select `Hex` from the left options.  The result is the hex error code.

Moderate:

Write a program that takes the error code and converts it to hex.

Hardest:

Convert the integer value to signed two's complement binary by hand.